# pyqt: How to dynamically update widget property on outer variable value change?

Tags: python, pyqt, signals-slots

I have `class Ui_MainWindow(object)` that creates a window with a progress bar and `class OtherClass(object)` that contains method in which the local int variable increments in cycle.

How to connect local variable value change to progres bar value change?

## mainGUI.py

```
import sys
from PyQt4.uic.Compiler.qtproxies import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from Ui_MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## Ui_MainWindow.py

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from MainGui.OtherClass import OtherClass

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def myButtonSlot(self):
        objVar=OtherClass()
        objVar.method()

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(389, 332)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))

        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.myButtonSlot)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)

        self.progressBar = QtGui.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget) 
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("progressBar"))

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.progressBar)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 389, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "PushButton", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

## OtherClass.py

```
class OtherClass(object):  
    def method(self):
        for i in range(100): # i want to connect variable i to progress bar value
            print i 
            for j in range(100500):
                pass
```

Comment: Please show the code that you have so far.

Answer (score 10):

You need to re-organize your code a little bit.

Firstly, you should *never* edit the code in the UI module generated by `pyuic`. Instead, import it into your main module and implement all your application logic there.

Secondly, you should create a main-window class in your main module, and do all the setup inside its `__init__` method.

One way to solve your problem of connecting the loop variable to the progress bar, is to make `OtherClass` a subclass of `QObject` and emit a custom signal:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class OtherClass(QtCore.QObject):
    valueUpdated = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def method(self):
        # i want to connect variable i to progress bar value
        for i in range(100):
            print i
            self.valueUpdated.emit(i)
            for j in range(100500):
                pass
```

With that in place, you would then move the setup for `pushButton` and its slot to "mainGUI.py", and re-generate "Ui_MainWindow.py" with `pyuic`. A slot would then be added to handle the custom `valueChanged` signal, which would update the progress bar and also process any pending GUI events.

So "mainGUI.py" would end up looking something like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from Ui_MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow
from OtherClass import OtherClass

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.myButtonSlot)
        self.otherclass = OtherClass(self)
        self.otherclass.valueUpdated.connect(self.handleValueUpdated)

    def myButtonSlot(self):
        self.otherclass.method()

    def handleValueUpdated(self, value):
        self.progressBar.setValue(value)
        QtGui.qApp.processEvents()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Answer (score 4):

The following post has a version that increments the progress bar 10% each time you press the button. And a version which uses a timer to increment the progress bar. (I'm just in the process of learning this myself)

In Qt Designer, add a progress bar and a button. Click on 'Edit Signals/Slots', drag a line from the button to somewhere in the window and when the button is 'pressed()' add a slot(or signal??) called 'button_pressed()' (use the + button to make this). When you have done this, the OK button is greyed out - select the slot you made, and press OK.

Save the file as ui_MainWindow.ui (note the capitals carefully).
Convert to a py file using the batch file >

```
pyuic4 -x ui_MainWindow.ui -o ui_MainWindow.py
```

This file should look something like....(you don't need to edit this).

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.progressBar = QtGui.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 90, 118, 23))
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("progressBar"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 200, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("pressed()")), MainWindow.button_pressed)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Create a 'program.py' file. This is the file you will run...

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
#from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets #works for pyqt5
from mainWindow import MainWindow

def main():
    #app = QtWidgets.QApplication (sys.argv) #works for pyqt5
    app = QtGui.QApplication (sys.argv) #works for pyqt4
    m = MainWindow ()
    m.show ()
    sys.exit (app.exec_ () )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main ()
```

Now this is where the good stuff happens when you subclass the mainwindow. Call this file 'mainWindow.py'. Careful with the capitalizations.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from ui_MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow #note the capitalization

class MainWindow (QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super (MainWindow, self).__init__ ()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow ()
        self.ui.setupUi (self)
        #------------do your custom stuff from here on-----------
        self.progress = 0 #Start value of progress bar
        self.ui.progressBar.setValue(self.progress)

    def button_pressed(self):
        print('button pressed')
        self.ui.statusbar.showMessage(str(self.progress)) #this is at bottom left of window. Discovered this accidentially when doing this!
        self.ui.progressBar.setValue(self.progress)
        self.progress+=10
```

There is a good tutorial [here](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/widgets/) which I used to create an alternate 'mainWindow.py' which uses a timer to increment the progress bar. It does not block the code with a loop using sleep or by doing a CPU intensive loop. I don't understand multithreading, multi-processor options yet to comment on using these.

```
#from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets #works for PyQt5
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from ui_MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow #note the capitalization

class MainWindow (QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super (MainWindow, self).__init__ ()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow () #same name as appears in mainWindowUi.py
        self.ui.setupUi (self)
        self.progress = 0 #Start value of progress bar
        self.ui.progressBar.setValue(self.progress)

        self.timer = QtCore.QBasicTimer()

    def button_pressed(self):
        self.timerEvent(64) #this needs an argument to work but I'm not sure what is is yet so I just put in some random number

    def timerEvent(self, e):
        self.ui.progressBar.setValue(self.progress)
        if self.progress >=100:
            self.timer.stop()
       else:
            if self.timer.isActive():
                pass
            else:
                self.timer.start(10,self) #10 milliseconds
        self.progress+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a signal and slot...and multiprocessing or multithreading.

There's a good example here that specifically takes you through the progress bar:
[ZetCode Progress Bar](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/widgets/)

Also, question has been answered here before:
[SO Progress Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269936/python-qt-progressbar)