# Python: Is there something like waitbar of matlab?

Tags: python, for-loop, progress-bar, progress

my situation is: I have a for loop in which simulations are done and it takes around 2 days until it is finished. Therefore I want to implement a GUI with a progressbar. In MATLAB I used waitbar.

But how do I do this in Python?
My aim is that the progressbar is updated after each iteration. But I dont want to use multithreading because that would be wastage(only one information is updated every 2 or 3 minutes). So the GUI should kept open in the background and after each iteration the progressbar should be updated.
I hope you understand what I mean.

```
    start progressbar

    for k in range(2000)

        update progressbar
        .
        .
        simulation is done
        .
        .
    close progressbar
```

So this should be done without multithreading.
I know how I build the GUI with the progressbar, but I dont know how I can update it.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Take a look: https://bitbucket.org/takluyver/progress_meter/src/b7c3831fe5d26476983949ffa733b6c2fbc600f2/progress_meter.py?at=default

Comment: forgot to say, I am using PyQt4. but thanks, I will look at it! :-)

Comment: Is this question useful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269936/python-qt-progressbar ?