# How to make a progressbar in PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am making a GUI application in Python. It has some radial button and I would like to show a progressBar while the `script.main()` finish and then shows the `MessageBox`:

```
def ejecuta(self):
    if self.ui.radioButton_1.isChecked()== True:
        script1.main()
        QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self,'Mensaje','Finalizado')
```

How can I do that?

Comment: look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442443/busy-indication-with-pyqt-progress-bar),[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269936/python-qt-progressbar), [here](https://acaciaecho.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/pyqtprogressbar/), [here](https://gist.github.com/mauriciodev/1118585), and [here](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/widgets/). The last site has a ton of examples for all types of widgets.

Comment: Also, if you search the PyQt4 or Qt4 docs for "progress bar" you'll find [`QProgressBar`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qprogressbar.html).