# update text in a Qt interface from method not in main script

Tags: python, while-loop, pyqt, qtextedit

I want to call in my main program a method `ExecuteM` where in a `while` loop a text in my interface in Qt (call `result`), done with Qt creator will be update for each iteration.

```
class Machine():
    def __init__(self, result):
        self.result=result

    def ExecuteM(self, Var1, Var2):
        while Var1 != 'stop':
            Var2 = Var2 + 3
            self.result.setText(newResult())
            sleep(0.5)
```

then in my main script:

```
def main(self):
    self.TM=Machine(self.result)
    self.TM.ExecuteM(var1, var2)
```

but it does not work the text does not update at each iteration, why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you execute a while-loop in the main thread, it will block the gui. All events will be queued until the while-loop terminates and control can return to the event-loop. So you either have to move the blocking while-loop into a separate thread, or periodically force the event-loop to process the pending events. In your example, it should probably be possible to achieve the latter like this:

```
    def ExecuteM(self, Var1, Var2):
        while Var1 != 'stop':
            Var2 = Var2 + 3
            self.result.setText(newResult())
            QApplication.processEvents()
            sleep(0.5)
```

But that's just a short-term solution. It would probably be better to [use a worker thread and send a custom signal back to the main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40595722/984421).

Comment: thanks, I think i start to understand the idea. But when I try your short-term solution I get :     `QApplication.processEvents()
NameError: global name 'QApplication' is not defined` ...?

Comment: @Dadep. You need to import it - or maybe use `QtGui.QApplication` (or `QtWidgets.QApplication` for PyQt5).

Comment: It was a problem of `from PyQt4.QtCore import *, from PyQt4.QtGui import * ` ...  Ah yes exactly ! (I was writing comment at the same time) Thanks